# Calling C# collection using Ajax to GridView

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, jquery

Why i get error when i call this collection? All i need to to bind this collection to my Gridview control.....

C# Code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{

    using (masterEntities context = new masterEntities())
    {
        return context.Customer.ToList();
    }


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("id");
    table.Columns.Add("Name");
table.Columns.Add("Age");
    table.Rows.Add();
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Ajax code:

```
  function GetCustomers() {

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "12.aspx/GetAllCustomers",
          data: '{}',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: OnSuccess,


          error: function (data) {
              alert(data.d);
          }


      });

      function OnSuccess(data) {

          for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

              $("#GridView1").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].Id + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Name    + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].Age + "</td></tr>");


          }

      }
```

This is what i get when i call that collection
http://s22.postimg.org/6qv6tr8g1/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `$.ajax` error handler:

```
error: function (data) {
              alert(data.d);
          }
```

Error hanlder written like this, gives you very little information on what happened with the failed request. A better way to write your error handler would be like this:

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                }
```

With error handler written this way you can look e.g. Chrome Developer Tools's console window and see the value of jqXHR.responseText which contains detailed error description of what went wrong.

Although be careful to replace console.log statements with more meaningful error messages when you deploy your web applications.

Here's a link to jQuery API documentation (look for error handler description): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Uros

Comment: and what is the value of jqXHR.responseText?